# How to add symbols from csv file

Tags: tables, symbols, pgfplotstable, csv

Is there any way to read symbols from a CSV file using `pgfplotstable`.

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
    a, b,  c 
    x,  1,  nearrow
    y,  2,  earrow
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread[
    col sep=semicolon,
    ]{data.csv}\data
        \footnotesize{
        \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        string type,
    ]\data}

\end{document}
```

Where I would want the `pgfplotstable` to read the c column with `$\` before and `$` after for the `$\nearrow$` symbol to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work. I replaced `earrow` with `to`, because the former doesn't exist (in `symbols-a4.pdf` at least).

Note that `8pt` isn't a valid option for `article`, though it is so for `extarticle`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
    a, b,  c 
    x,  1,  nearrow
    y,  2,  to
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread[
    col sep=comma,
    ]{data.csv}\data

\footnotesize{%
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  string type,
  columns/c/.style={
     preproc cell content/.append style={
        /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={$\csname}{\endcsname$}
     }
  }
  ]\data}

\end{document}
```